# Finding unique permutations efficiently

Tags: matlab, math, permutation, combinatorics

I have the following problem.  I need to compute the permutations of a set; however, the set may contain two elements which are the same and therefore cause repeated permutations.  For example:

Given the set `[ 0 0 1 2 ]`, the permutations include these possibilities:

```
 1     2     0     0
 1     2     0     0
```

However, I would like to avoid identical permutations such as these.  In MATLAB I can simply do this:

```
unique(perms([ 0 0 1 2 ]), 'rows')
```

But the problem here is efficiency - I am doing this repeatedly in a huge `for` loop and the sorting required by `unique` is too slow.  So my question is: can I compute unique permutations of this nature *directly* without having to loop through the result afterwards?  I am working in MATLAB but just a general solution would probably be helpful, although something which can be vectorized in MATLAB would probably be ideal!

As far as I can see existing questions do not cover exactly this problem, but apologies if this has been answered before.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Why do you have a loop in which you need to find permutations of different arrays at high speed?

Comment: Good point, perhaps I should have been more specific, although it gets a bit messy.  I'm finding ways of corresponding sets of objects between images, although the objects have a class associated with them.  I take 5 objects from at a time from set A, and find all the ways of corresponding them to objects in set B.  I tackle the class restrictions by finding permutations within each class.  This is why there are zeros: they represent an object not being paired to another, which is why I do not want to repeat such permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear this is a regularly occurring problem. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164470) is a file by John d'Errico (`uniqueperms`) that seems to tackle it pretty effectively. As an alternative, there is another FEX submission [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27321-unique-random-permutations) by Ged Ridgway; you'll have to profile a bit to see which one is faster.

Note that due to the limitations of Matlab's JIT, loops are not accelerated if they call non-builtin functions, so it might be beneficial to copy-paste the contents of these functions (and/or specialize them a bit) inside your loop(s).

Comment: Ah that's it, thank you very much!  My Googling abilities obviously need practice!