# Difficulties building vector of functions for fsolve

Tags: matlab, function, loops, optimization, vector

I am trying to implement a program using `fsolve` in matlab. I want the program to be able to compare n elements pairwise and where each comparison is a row in a function vector F of which `fsolve` is then applied to.

So far I have written the program for 3 elements (comparing 1 and 2,1 and 3, 2 and 3), writing each function explicitly which works as wanted. But I have now tried constructing the function vector in a loop inside a matlab function. However this does not seem to work since the function is called in every iteration of `fsolve` and therefore the values change in a unexpected way. Any advise on what could be done?

And the main program looks as follows:

```
A = [1 1;-1 -1;-1 1;1 -1];

U =[0 0];

Ustart= [6 7]; 

f= @(Uest)TimeDiffs(U,A,Ustart);
```

And the function TimeDiffs looks as follow:

```
function F = TimeDiffs(U,A,Uest)

F=[];
funcnum=1;

    for q= 1:length(A)

        for p= q+1:length(A)

            td= norm(U-A(q,:))-norm(U-A(p,:));

            F(funcnum)= norm(Uest-A(q,:))-norm(Uest-A(p,:))-td;
            funcnum=funcnum+1;

        end
    end
end
```

There seems to be an issue when using a loop in a function that is used in `fsolve`. Has anyone had any similiar experience?

Comment: what is your expected output you want to generate in TimeDiffs?

Comment: A vector with each different  nonlinear function (function = 0) on each row, as required by fsolve. @m.s.

Comment: Looks like you need to generate unique permutations of the set `[1,2,...n]`, right? If yes, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109710/finding-unique-permutations-efficiently, otherwise you might need to specify your problem more clearly.

Comment: Yes sorry I could have been more clear. Finding a method for the permutations has not been the problem, however it seems as if the loops used don't do well in `fsolve`. I have updated the question with my current implementation. @m.s.